# Community has wrong avatar

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[Community](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/-1/community)'s avatar is wrong. Fix, please.

Comment: It has the "wrong" avatar?  What would the right avatar be?

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork It had. "It was completed while on MSE: meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/230044/2 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Just the SE logo. It's the same as the main site, and all the other sites I've checked.

If it's still wrong for you, could you try clearing your local cache. Might also be a proxy issue if your network uses one. In the future please include a screen shot if you're reporting a display/layout issue.

Comment: It was completed while on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/230044/2